# Calling a function locally or remotely

Tags: algorithm

I have a hypothetical software which has two components A and B. Component B can be deployed locally on same machine as A or component B ca be deployed remotely. I want to know if there is a technique/method/configuration in any programming language which can handle the call to B's API transparently, irrespective of B whether deployed locally or remotely. To end developer it should appear as same function call.

Comment: RPC and local calls will always have quite different reliability and performance characteristics, so as you ask the question it's not really possible to "transparently" switch one for the other.

Comment: you can check "A note on distributed computing" for a critique of this approach

Answer (score 0):

If you use a remote call (e.g. by using .net remoting or Java RMI), the call can be performed even the two components are deployed on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can use `COM/DCOM` to achieve what you want to achieve. From the programs point of view, the component may either be remote or local it doesn't matter, it is still instantiated and used in the same manner.

Comment: In COM/DCOm will the call to locally deployed component be a local function call? I want to avoid sockets when the component is present on the same machine and invoke the API via a direct function call. But when the component is remotely deployed, the system should use RPC or any other mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done just by keeping that B's API Url or location as an configurable one in one of your config files of your application and trying to acces this config setting all over the application , one thing that needs to be done is to point to local API or Remote Api.

> So as for as the end developer is concerned the change would be only in the config file of your application and the remaining function calls remain same irrespective of whether the component B's is deployed locally or remotely.
>
> Eg: An Php application trying access an API webservice deployed anywhere over the internet.

Thanks

Comment: When you are quoting text, prefix the lines with the > character.  Indenting by four spaces formats the text as code, eliminating line wrapping and making the text a little harder to read.